# Media keys in WndProc not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc, media-keys

I am creating a media player in WinForms, C#. I want to respond to the user pressing the multimedia keys on the keyboard using the following code that can be found all over the internet:

```cs
public const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x0319;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_APPCOMMAND)
    {
        switch ((int)m.LParam)
        {
            case 14: // MediaPlayPause
                TogglePlayPause();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

But it won't work. It just never recieves the key command. Media keys work with every other application (and the `TogglePlayPause()` method works as well).

Answer (score 1):

The value reported by `LParam` is a composite one.

As specified in the Docs, about [WM_APPCOMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-appcommand), the value can be extracted using:

```
cmd  = GET_APPCOMMAND_LPARAM(lParam);
uDevice = GET_DEVICE_LPARAM(lParam);
dwKeys = GET_KEYSTATE_LPARAM(lParam);
```

You need the `cmd` value.

In `C#`, it can be coded as:

```
private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x0319;
private const int APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 14;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_APPCOMMAND:
            int cmd = (int)m.LParam >> 16 & 0xFF;
            switch (cmd)
            {
                case APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                    TogglePlayPause();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
Some meaningful links about KeyBoard Hooks and registering HotKeys.

On [`SetWindowHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw):
[SetWindowsHookEx WH_KEYBOARD_LL not getting events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746071/setwindowshookex-wh-keyboard-ll-not-getting-events?answertab=active#tab-top)
[Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/)

On [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey):
[Capture a keyboard keypress in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413172/capture-a-keyboard-keypress-in-the-background)

Comment: That works flawlessly, but only when the window is focused. Is there a way to make this work even when the application is minimized?

Comment: @Jonas Kohl  You need a KeyBoard Hook or HotKeys, depending on how your application works (and how well you can manage the quirks of concurrency). Links to both methods in the Edit. This is, however, a different question and quite a broad one. Make another question if you have any problems implementing one of the methods (don't use both).