# Integrate GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote my own MediaPlayer because I found no player I like, which integrates the [*GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssession?view=winrt-19041). So I wrote my own player... which also does not integrate them. So I want to change it.

So how do I register a session, pass the metadata and react on control commands (play, pause, skip next, skip previous, ...). I don't want to listen for virtual keys (like VLC) because they only work when the window is focused.

Comment: Build an UWP app? In case you just need to intercept Media Commands, see here: [Media keys in WndProc not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026949/7444103).

Comment: But my app is no UWP app and for example, Spotify, Chrome, Firefox, ... are no UWP apps and they integrate them. So it should be possible

Comment: You mean this one: [MediaPlayerElement control for Windows Forms and WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/mediaplayerelement). That documentation contain the *instruction* to use UWP Control in WPF and WinForms, using [XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands). Not sure it's enough. See the general [Windows Community Toolkit Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/).

Comment: @Jimi Okay I integrated the control. The session is created but I cannot control it using *TryPauseAsync*, *TryPlayAsync*, ... Also I have to fill in the metadata. How do I do this?